# JTabbedPane created dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have a problem when I try to crete dynamically Tabs on a JTabbePane by a for. The problem is that I don't know how to access the contents when an event happens.
I will try to show you  part of the code to be easy to understand.

```
            conteudoT = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    conteudoT.setBounds(5, 19, 477, 232);

    for (int i = 0; i < players; i++) {

        conteudo = new JPanel();
        conteudo.setLayout(null);

        Details = new JPanel();
        Details.setBounds(15, 11, 307, 183);
        Details.setVisible(false);
        Details.setName("Details" + i);
        conteudo.add(Details);

                    btnR = new JButton("r");
                    btnR.addActionListener(this);

        conteudoT.addTab("Jogador " + (i + 1), conteudo);
        Details.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 0, 0));
                    ... 
                    contentPane.add(conteudoT);

                    }


    @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    for (int i = 0; i <  players; i++) {
        if (e.getSource()==btnR) {
            Details.setVisible(true); 

        }
    }
    }
```

What happens here is that the painel Details is added on the last Tab to be constructed and I would like to add it on the Tab that the event happend.

Comment: Use a `Map` to link the `JButton` to your `Details` pane.  Take the time to learn how to use layout managers and save your sanity.  Also take the time to learn the [coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) of the Java language and save our (sanity) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use :

```
conteudoT.indexOfTab(string)
```

to get the index. Then use :

```
conteudoT.getTabComponentAt(int index)
```

to get the component

Comment: Thanks, but the problem was solved with another class.Was the only way to access the distinct tabs.